# Why are conversion characters needed?

Tags: c, printf

When I run this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int x = 1;
    
    printf(x, "\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me these errors:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)
>
> Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)
>
> Treat the string as an argument to avoid this
>
> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *'

And it outputs:

> (lldb)

However, when I change it to:

```
printf("%s", x);
```

It works perfectly fine. (outputs "1", as expected)

**Why are the conversion characters (e.g. %s, %d, etc...) needed?**

Comment: Your code is undefined behavior in both cases, `printf("%s", x);` does not work fine if `x` is of type `int`. You cannot expect to get any particular behavior from it. Have you read [the manual of `printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)? [It explains how it works.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: *"and it outputs `(lldb)`"* -- okay, I know that's undefined behavior... but a program with undefined behavior that debugs itself? That's next level.

Answer (score 2):

They parameters are not "conversion characters". I think your confusion comes from the fact that you think `printf` simply prints all its arguments and automatically deduces how to print each. However, `printf` cannot work like that because C does not have support for overloading.

Concretely, the first argument is not like the rest. It is *not* something to print, but a format string. You can see easily what it means by trying this:

```
printf("My friend %s has %d coins!", "John", 123);
```

which will print:

```
My friend John has 123 coins!
```

`%s` here specifies the first argument (after the format string) will be interpreted as a string, and `%d` means the second argument (again, after the format string) will be understood as an integer. Both will be replaced with the actual value from the argument.

Comment: They are characters, and they specify conversions. Why are they not conversion characters?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was referring to the parameters in general. I understood that OP thought that each parameter was something to print (i.e. rather than specifying arguments and a format string to apply them too). I agree it can be misleading, I will clarify the answer.

Answer (score 2):

They're needed to tell the `printf` function what the types (and number) of the parameters are that you are passing.

The language has no mechanism to allow a function to determine this dynamically, so the format string gives it the clues to decode them.

The format string is always the first parameter, because the called function can always access that in the same place. Functions like printf are still written in C typically, so can only use those functions that the language provides.

Comment: No, the format string used **not** to tell the compiler anything. The compiler just generates code to give all arguments to the called function. The format string tells the function `printf()` how to handle these arguments and what to expect -- see also "variadic arguments." However, nowadays compilers will do a check that the format string and the arguments match. But you could put a format string in a variable, dynamically built, and then this check can't be done.

Comment: @thebusybee Absolutely. That's what I meant to write. My brain was running ahead of my typing...

Comment: @thebusybee: Per the C standard, `printf` is part of the C implementation, and how the work is divided between the compiler, a `printf` implementation, and any other components of the implementation is up to the implementation. Good modern compilers will examine the format string at compile time and could replace `printf` with `puts` and a fixed string, for example. So we cannot say the format string is not used to tell the compiler anything.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's what BusyBee said. "...used not to tell..." has a very different meaning to "not used to tell".

Comment: @Roddy: But it **is** used to tell the implementation, including the compiler—it is not used not to tell. People may think of it sending information to `printf` and not sending information to the compiler, and that is certainly the way it evolved originally, but it is not the current specification and is not what happens in good modern implementations.

Comment: It would be nice if `printf` could be optimized into `fputs` if all the arguments and everything were known at compile-time.

Comment: Re: "The language has no mechanism to allow a function to determine this dynamically,", code use   [`_Generic`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485)

Comment: @chux - Fair point. C11 has rather passed me by. Where's it actually used?

Comment: What is passed to functions, including `...` ones remains the same.  Yet with `_Generic_`, the compiler can detect the type and emit different code.  I am unfamiliar with any run-time distinction - perhaps made with various array size due to VLA.